# Converting seconds to hours and minutes and seconds

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int seconds, hours, minutes;
    cin >> seconds;
    hours = seconds/3600;
    cout << seconds << " seconds is equivalent to " << int(hours) << " hours " << seconds%(hours*60) 
         << " minutes " << (seconds%(hours*3600))-((seconds%(hours*60))*60) << " seconds.";
}
```

For some reason, this program works with only numbers above 3600. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Whenever I do a number below 3600, the screen shows up with a message from Windows saying that the program has stopped working.

Comment: By now you've probably figured it out, but when `seconds` is less than `3600`, divide by zero occurs in subsequent steps.  When that happens, Windows immediately rewards you by taking away your process.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this out instead, tested and works:

```
int seconds, hours, minutes;
cin >> seconds;
minutes = seconds / 60;
hours = minutes / 60;
cout << seconds << " seconds is equivalent to " << int(hours) << " hours " << int(minutes%60) 
     << " minutes " << int(seconds%60) << " seconds.";
```

Because minutes is seconds/60, dividing it by 60 again is equivalent to diving seconds by 3600, which is why it works.

Comment: Problem with this is that if seconds surpass like days then this wont work.... eg. 777600 seconds = 9 days. then 777600/60 = 12960 minutes.

Answer (score 17):

`seconds/3600` is integer division, so for `seconds < 3600`, `hours` is `0`, then things like `seconds%(hours*3600)` becomes `seconds % 0`, causing a division-by-zero.

---

Let's first get the logic right. Suppose you want to write `5000 seconds` as `x` hours `y` minutes `z` seconds, such that all three are integers and neither `y` nor `z` is greater than 59. What do you do?

Well, you can first write it as `q` minutes `z` seconds, such that both are integers and `z` is not greater than 59. That's easy:

```
q = 5000 / 60 = 83  // integer division
z = 5000 % 60 = 20
```

So 5000 seconds is 83 minutes 20 seconds. Now how do you write `83 minutes` into `x` hours `y` minutes, such that both are integers and `y` is no greater than 59? You do the same thing:

```
x = 83 / 60 = 1
y = 83 % 60 = 23
```

OK, let's generalize this:

```
int total, seconds, hours, minutes;
cin >> total;
minutes = total / 60;
seconds = total % 60;
hours = minutes / 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
cout << total << " seconds is equivalent to " << hours << " hours " << minutes 
     << " minutes " << seconds << " seconds.\n" ;
```

Comment: @SeanChen: by thinking a little bit and doing some very basic "math". How would *you* convert (on paper with a pencil!) seconds to hours and minutes and seconds

Answer (score 2):

You've got a divide-by-zero problem here:

```
seconds % (hours*60);
```

`hours` is 0 by virtue of integer division.

```
hours = seconds/3600;
```

From what you're trying to do, you should consider conditional logic to print the minutes if the total number of seconds is greater than 3600.  You'll also want to investigate similar logic in the next part of your print stream.

My C++ is rusty, so forgive if this isn't *exactly* valid syntax:

```
cout << (seconds > 3600 ? seconds % (hours*60) : seconds) << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int totalSecond;
cin >> totalSecond;

int hour = totalSecond / 3600;
int minute = (totalSecond % 3600) / 60;
int second = totalSecond % 60;

cout << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << endl;
```

Assuming that `totalSeconds` is the number of seconds since midnight and is less than 86400

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast), one can simply write (refer [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) for more options):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
  int s; std::cin >> s;
  seconds sec(s);
  std::cout << duration_cast<hours>(sec).count() << ':'
            << duration_cast<minutes>(sec).count() % 60 << ':'
            << sec.count() % 60;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With c++20 this gets pretty easy using [`std::chrono::hh_mm_ss`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main ()
{
    int seconds;
    std::cin >> seconds;
    std::chrono::hh_mm_ss time{std::chrono::seconds(seconds)};
    std::cout << seconds << " seconds is equivalent to " << time.hours().count() << " hours " << time.minutes().count() 
         << " minutes " << time.seconds().count() << " seconds.";
}
```

Comment: Upvoted.  But you no longer need the `.count()` to print out durations.  `..." seconds is equivalent to " << time.hours() << " " << time.minutes()
         << " " << time.seconds() << ...`

Comment: @HowardHinnant without count it'll add the suffixes though which wouldn't produce the expected output: https://godbolt.org/z/1qvdGqjcM

Answer (score 1):

by using function;

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;
    int hour(int h)
    {
        int second;
        //second=(h/3600);
        if (h>3600)
            second=h/3600;
        else 
           second=(h/3600);
        return (second);
    }

    int minute(int m)
    {
        int second2;
        second2=(   );
        return(second2);
    }

    int second(int s)
    {
        int second3;
        second3=((s-3600)%60);
        return (second3);
    }

    void main()
    {
        int convert;
        cout<<"please enter seconed to convert it to hour\b";

        cin>>convert;
        cout<<"hr : min : sec \n";
        cout<<hour(convert)<<":"<<minute(convert)<<":"<<second(convert)<<endl;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One string convertion from seconds to `hh:mm:ss` format:

```c
sprintf(tempBuffer, "%02u:%02u:%02u", _time / 3600, (_time % 3600) / 60, _time % 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Until now none of the presented solution have in count the day duration. I had to write a clock to use in arduino, the millis() function return milliseconds since turn on, to get seconds just divide by 1000.

```
void showTime(unsigned long  seconds){
  
   printf( "seconds : %lu ", seconds); 
   int hh = (seconds/3600) %24;
   int mm = (seconds/60) %60;
   int ss = seconds%60;
   printf( " Time : %2d:%02d:%02d\n", hh, mm,ss);

   }

   showTime( 0*24*3600 +  4*3600+35*60+25); // 0d+4hs+35m+25s; 
   showTime( 2*24*3600 +  1*3600+45*60+59); // 2d+1hs+45m+59s; 
   showTime(40*24*3600 + 10*3600+ 5*60+10); // 40d+10hs+5m+10s;
```

wath print:

```
seconds : 189325  Time :  4:35:25
seconds : 6359  Time :  1:45:59
seconds : 3492360  Time : 10:06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int h,m,s;
    cout << "Time in Seconds = ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "H:M:S - " << s / 3600 << ":" << (s % 3600) / 60 << ":" << s % 60;
```

Input:

```
Time in Seconds = 25300
```

Output:

```
H:M:S - 7:1:40
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int seconds;
  cout << "Enter an integer for seconds: ";
  cin >> seconds;
  int minutes = seconds / 60;
  int remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  cout << seconds << " seconds is " << minutes <<
    " minutes and " << remainingSeconds << " seconds " << endl;

  return 0;

}
```